# Keep a ES module outside the bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

My application has a configuration file

**external-config.js**

```
import {constants} from "./constants.js";

export const ExternalConfig = {
    title: "My application",
    version: "2.0",
    constants: constants
    list: ["uno", "due", "tre"]
}
```

I don't want it to be bundled with the application, I want to keep it outside. I tried the `IgnorePlugin`, but apparently this simply breaks the dependency graph and I get the error  `ReferenceError: Config is not defined` even if the reference to the path of the config file in the budle is correct.

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
            checkResource (resource) {
                if (resource === "./conf/external-config.js") return true;
                return false;
            }
        })
]
```

I cannot even import it in the main html page like

```
<script type="module" src="./conf/config.js"></script>
```

because in this way I couldn't access the object outside its own script.
Is there a way to do that?

---

EDIT: following @raz-nonen advice, I tried `null-loader`, it seems it could be a solution. The problem with that is the physical position of the configuration file.

```
rules: [
            {
                test: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/conf/external-config.js"),
                use: "null-loader"
            }
    ...]
```

And this is the result in the built script

```
// EXTERNAL MODULE: ./src/conf/external-config.js
var external_config = __webpack_require__(13);
```

But the actual position of the configuration in the `dist` folder is `./conf/external-config.js`, not `./src/conf/external-config.js`

This is the chunk of my app that consumes the external file

```
import {ExternalConfig} from "./conf/external-config.js";

class MyApp extends LitElement {
 constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(ExternalConfig.list)
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, what's the intent?

Comment: As I said, the aim to to bundle my application with webpack but keeping a configuration file (which is an ES Module) outside the bundle

Comment: Where are you importing it from? did you try `null-loader`?

Comment: @RazRonen I import and use the external module in my app of course (which is a `LitElement` WebComponent), more precisely in the body of the script defined as entrypoint in webpack (no 2nd level dependency). I suspect Externals https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/ could be useful, but it seems tailored for `node_modules` packages

Comment: @RazRonen please take a look  to the edit of the question, I added an issue with `null-loader`

Comment: The comment points to the module location before build so it make sense,
now the configuration content shouldn't be in the bundle. Isn't this what you wanted? Or am I missing something in your intent?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. I assumed that path refers to both source and built code because the built code throws the error `Cannot read property 'list' of undefined`.  Please refer to my second edit with `constructor` of my app. How can I make sure where the built code actually try to looks for the external file?

Comment: I wrote an answer that uses the `external` configuration, it seems more suitable for this case.

Answer (score 1):

1. You'll need to make this file available in the dist folder. You can do that with [copy-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin)
2. Tell webpack that ExternalConfig will be imported from `external`. It means that you'll have to take care that it'll be available at runtime. You can do it simply by importing your `conf/config.js` that you copied from a `<script>` tag in your index.html.

Add:

```
externals: {
   'conf/external-config': 'conf/external-config'
}
```

In your webpack configuration.

Comment: wait, of course in my example I use `copy-webpack-plugin` to copy the files I need (including external-config.js). I will try your solution, but the whole point of having an ES module and import it in the classical way using `import` is to avoid global object pollution. `window.ExternalConfig` doesn't looks like following that way

Comment: You are right regarding the global object pollution, I edited my answer. `window.ExternalConfig` isn't actually needed, as long as you make sure that the export of your ES5 module is what you want

Comment: Not sure if your usage of `externals` is correct, webpack still includes the module in the bundle. First of all I need to add the extension `.js` because I import it with the extension (plain browser usage), then a question: what exactly is supposed to be the key of the object?  Are you sure in my case should be `'conf/external-config'`? The webpack docs doesn't help since their examples show npm modules (react/jquery). Thanks

Comment: Actually I was aware of this ticket, I had it forgotten for the past few days https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8895 Basically I'm trying to do something not supported yet